# how to change query search in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, filter, query-optimization

I have a heavy site with over 200,000 articles
When searching in WordPress, this search looks for the desired word in the title, content, and excerpt
In this number of articles, the result of slow query is more than 50 seconds and slows down MariaDB

I want to write a filter to limit this query to only titles

I think this slow query will be fixed and the problem will be solved
Please help to write this filter or help if you know that the problem can be solved by another solution
Thank you

in the file
wp-includes/class-wp-query.php

i also have this problem in the admin panel, searching the posts and photo library that has over 250,000 photos

Comment: This does not address your question directly, but I had a similar problem and I started using the search plugin called Relevanssi. It uses far better search algorithms than the notoriously obtuse `content LIKE '%searchterm%'` SQL stuff in core WordPress. I don't know how well it handles RTL text, like in Arabic or Farsi.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this code and let me know if it work's.

```
function limit_search_to_titles($query) {
if ($query->is_search && !is_admin()) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'post'); // Adjust 'post' to match your custom post types if needed
    $query->set('posts_per_page', -1); // Include all results, you can limit this if necessary
    $query->set('s', ''); // Clear the search term
    $query->set('title', $query->query_vars['s']); // Set the title to the search term
} } add_action('pre_get_posts', 'limit_search_to_titles');
```

Comment: But in the admin panel
I have a problem searching the posts
I have this problem with the search panel in a photo library that has over 250,000 photos.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one

```
function custom_search_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search && ! is_admin() ) {
        
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'post' ); 
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
        $query->set( 's', get_query_var( 's' ) ); 

        // Modify the search query to search only in post titles.
        $query->set( 'title', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_search_query' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed this code on line 1632 to 1636

```
// Sentence match in 'post_content' and 'post_excerpt'.
if ( $like ) {
   $search_orderby .= $wpdb->prepare( "WHEN {$wpdb->posts}.post_excerpt LIKE %s THEN 4 ", $like );
   $search_orderby .= $wpdb->prepare( "WHEN {$wpdb->posts}.post_content LIKE %s THEN 5 ", $like );
}
```

and change line 1426

```
$default_search_columns = array( 'post_title', 'post_excerpt', 'post_content' );
```

to

```
$default_search_columns = array( 'post_title' );
```

and I think the problem is solved Can someone do this by writing a filter So that it does not cause problems in the next update of Wordpress